# When is it safe to call a shared library from multiple threads using JNA/JNI?

Tags: java, concurrency, native, jna, shared-libraries

I have compiled some `FORTRAN` subroutines into a `.so` file, and I am using `JNA` to call them from `Java`.

Is it safe to call the subroutines at the same time (reentrant) from multiple threads?

I don't think the subroutines keep any global state, but are there any requirements from `JNA`?

Comment: Um, what were those edits for? I didn't realize all programming languages and names of software had to be in fixed-width font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK JNA doesn't have any specific limitations of multi-threaded use.  At least I have assumed it doesn't and it hasn't shown a problem.  JNA is stateless so I would be surprised if it did.

Comment: Peter is correct, JNA holds no global state when invoking native functions, other than a handle to the native library itself.  If you want to ensure your FORTRAN code is never called concurrently, you can use [`Native.synchronizedLibrary()`](http://twall.github.com/jna/3.5.1/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Native.html#synchronizedLibrary(com.sun.jna.Library)